# Prove that $P(X \le n)-P(X+Y \le n)= \alpha P(X+Y=n)$

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be mutually independent random variables taking non-negative integer values.
Prove that $P(X \le n)-P(X+Y \le n)= \alpha P(X+Y=n)$ holds for $n=0,1,2,...$ and for some $\alpha>0$ iff $P[Y=n]=\frac{1}{1+ \alpha}(\frac{\alpha}{1+ \alpha})^n , n=0,1,2,...$
I have done enough research on this problem and I have come to know that this is Madan L Puri's Characterization of Geometric DIstribution.
Can anyone provide me a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Define $x_k = P(X = k)$ and $y_k = P(Y = k)$. Then write
$$P(X+Y\le n) = \sum_{i+j \le n} x_i y_j$$
and
$$P(X+Y = n) = \sum_{i+j = n} x_i y_j, \qquad P(X\le n) = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i$$
Then write the desired equality with $x_i$'s an $y_j$'s. On both sides, collect the terms in factor of a given $x_k$ and see if the geometric law for $Y$ gives the result.

I haven't checked the result but this is the strategy I would try.

Comment: Thanks, by your method the only if part is done..Can you prove the if part?

Comment: Yes , the 2nd part is also done!! great solution man